Looking for a fanfic where Sirius has a daughter with a Star
This fanfic I read about 3 years ago: Sirius has a daughter who ended up being raised at Malfoy Manor. She befriends Dobby and starts going on adventures, realizing she is very powerful. It turns out her mother was a "star." The story goes through the entire events of Harry Potter but from this girl's perspective. I think her name was Caris, but I might be misremembering that. She even time travels and travels to other worlds.
Anyone know what this is?
